# swift do task after the preview task is finished

Tags: mysql, swift, core-data

In my swift 2 app i would like to make an http-post-request to get data of my mysql database. After that I would like to write this data into my core data.

I have the code part for request and write.

How do I get the following structure.

1. Request Data
2. if request data complete write in into core data

Could this be the correct thing?

This is my SyncMYSQL function in my Sync.swift file.

```
class func SyncMYSQL() {

        print("START SYNC MYSQL")

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
        let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()



            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://xxx")!)
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            let postString = "userid=12"


            request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
                data, response, error in

                // if no internet connection
                guard error == nil && data != nil else {
                    print("error=\(error)")
                    return
                }

                let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!


                let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ITEMS")
                fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

                do {
                    let results = try managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
                    for managedObject in results {
                        let managedObjectData:NSManagedObject = managedObject as! NSManagedObject
                        managedObjectContext!.deleteObject(managedObjectData)
                    }
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("Detele all data in ITEMS error : \(error) \(error.userInfo)")
                }



                var x = 0
                while (x < responseString.count ) {


                    let newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("ITEMS", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!) as! CoreData_ITEMS
                    newItem.name = responseString[x]
                    x++
                }

                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                    print("FINISH MYSQL")
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
                });

            }
            task.resume()
        }
```

This function i call from my view controller like this way:

```
func RequestData() {

        Sync.SyncMYSQL()
print ("Start Core Data")

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ITEMS")
        do {
            try data = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [CoreData_ITEMS]
        } catch { }



        Table.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: the code you have posted is to handle asynch operations. so code that should run in the back.

Comment: but it sure is a good idea to run tasks like that in the back.

Comment: If you say, you already have the code for write and for request, then yes. you should put that into the async code, that you've just posted. but that way I don't get the point of your thread

Comment: but this doesn't work correctly. i have set an print() into the request , request finished and the write part. this is my log: (CORE DATA has to start AFTER SYNC MYSQ)

'START SYNC MYSQL; START CORE DATA; FINISH SYNC MYSQL'

Comment: have you tryed your request/write code without async method? does this work?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35774337/swift-sync-data-of-core-data-an-mysql-database) What's the problem with that?

Comment: that i dont use this code. i searching for a step by step solution,David at the moment i use the code with async methods. but this doesn't solve my problem

Comment: your problem can't be solved that way. I don't know how to help you, if you don't post the complete code. you just say, that it does not work.

Comment: i updated my first post with my code

Comment: and sry, i have to correct myself. i request the data and write it into core data after the request is complete. but the request of core data and the reload of my table have to be the next step after this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use closure blocks as callback when the operation ends

```
class func SyncMYSQL(onSuccess: ()->()){

    // your custom events
    // your custom events
    // your custom events

    if MYSQLisSynced == true {
        // when MYSQL is synced you can call the success block
        onSuccess()
    }

}
```

In other file when you call the function SyncMYSQL() you have to specify the on success block

```
SyncMYSQL { () -> () in
    //custom callback actions
}
```

Comment: YES, THAT IT IS !! Thanks. little question at the end. can you explain my how this code works? i would like to understand it :)